# How to wrap the datepicker in a new div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to put my datepicker in a new div, that will be a (shadow-)border-div.

I've tried the following:

```
beforeShow: function (input) {
  $(input).datepicker("widget")
   .find(".ui-datepicker-header, ui-datepicker-calendar")
   .wrapAll("<div class='datepickerBorder'/>");
}
```

But it does not work.

Additionally I've tried to wrap the whole picker, but then the border-div has not the same position, size, etc.

Comment: Do you mean the datepicker (calendar) element itself?

Comment: I mean the datepicker itself. But when I wrap the picker itself, then the border-div does not have the same position, size, etc. of the datepicker. Because of that, I thought of wrapping the child elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The datepicker control is absolutely positioned. Wrapping it inside an element will not **contain** the datepicker inside that element -- the wrapping element will just sit at the bottom of the page while the datepicker will render next to the control.

Solution 1: You can add the class to the datepicker widget itself:

```
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function() {
        $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("datepickerBorder");
    },
    onClose: function() {
        $(this).datepicker("widget").removeClass("datepickerBorder");
    }
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/BakWQ/)

Solution 2: create an absolutely positioned + hidden wrapping div on DOM load and re-position + re-size the div behind the datepicker when it shows. There is a catch: you cannot check the widget's offset (the co-ordinates at which it will render) inside the `beforeShow` function.

Comment: solution1 is working, but not really solving my problem. Because I need two borders (one normal and one for a "shadow") and one is always overwritten by the other.
solution2 is for my needs, but the problem with the offset makes it unusable. Is there a chance to get the offset?

Comment: No idea, may be you can use setInteval inside the beforeShow; check the datepicker widget's position 100 milliseconds after beforeShow was fired.

Comment: The thing with setTimeout inside beforeShow is the clue!

Comment: Solution 1 seems pointless to me.  jQuery UI is fully themeable, if you want e.g. a fat red border then just `.ui-datepicker { border:solid 10px red; }`  http://jsfiddle.net/VxNQW/

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#datepicker').wrap('<div class="datepickerBorder"/>');
```

Here `#datepicker` is the `id` of datepicker input field, you may have something else.

Check jQuery **[.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**.

You don't need to do this within `beforeShow()`. Do  it within DOM ready function.

To wrap each inner element of `datepicker` you should try

```
$('div#ui-datepicker-div > *').wrap('<div class='datepickerBorder'/>');
```

Comment: the wrapping is working. But then the border-div does not have the same position, size, etc. of the datepicker. Because of that, I thought of wrapping the child elements.

Comment: thanks. But as you can see here: http://www.suckmypic.net/5sUoo9sm.png no wrapping element if I try to wrap the children :(