# Append jQuery UI datepicker to specific div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jQuery datepicker with a series of input fields and would like the datepicker to be appended to the div containing the input field rather than to the body element the datepickers are rendered on.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a really generic question, do you have any code as to how you're implementing it?

Comment: Refer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812921/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-to-wrap-the-datepicker-in-a-new-div

Comment: The datepicker is being called on an input element that is contained inside a div with a class applied to it. E.g. <div class="datepicker-wrapper"><input class="datepicker"></div>. I need the datepicker appended to .datepicker-wrapper as opposed to body. Thanks!

Comment: I want to do just what you did! the answer of @Tom is not true, Why are you mark it as true answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Display the datepicker embedded in the page instead of in an overlay.
>   Simply call .datepicker() on a div instead of an input.

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: Even if it's accepted, this answer is totally unrelated to the problem and do not resolve it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351871/jquery-date-picker-not-moving-with-page-scroll

Comment: You are wrong. This answer does exactly what he wanted to accomplish. Please read his description and comment again.

He wants the node, with the code added with .datepicker(), appended to a specific div rather then the body element. $('div.datepicker-wrapper').datepicker() generates html inside that div. And thats what he wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/mnzdrkhu/

Comment: Appended to a specific div, yes, but popping out, not always visible. This is related to the scroll bug (that is at least 4 years old and obviously no developer of jqueryui is caring about)

Comment: Where do you read that he wants it to popup? That is not a requirement mentioned anywhere and easy enough to accomplish with a simple js or css where you set display: none to a focus event or something

Comment: This is not the answer, for example I want it to be appended to a `#wrapperdiv` where I can use specific css for the `#ui-datepicker-div`, I know it's kind of a hack, but important for some other reasons

Comment: Example: `#TecRMIProxyWrapper .ui-datepicker {
 width: 17em;
 padding: .2em .2em 0;
 display: none;
}` doesn't work since it's not appended to the proper div (dialogue works with a `.appendTo(...)`

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution which I've found is

```
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
    beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
        $('.DivToAppendPicker').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Although this does work, the dialog is still given a `top` and `left` style value, which means the picker does not appear near the intended position. I tried setting the CSS as part of the above solution, but jQueryUI is overwriting it.  Haven't figured out a way of solving

Comment: After asking my own question, there is a [solution to the position issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69487688/930393) - although it's not perfect