# Append jQueryUI datepicker to div (wrong display position)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I'm using jQueryUI datepicker on an input, and as default jQueryUI appends the `#ui-datepicker-div` to the `body` of the document.

The input in question is in a "popup" div on the screen, meaning any click outside of that div will close the "popup".

Because jQueryUI is appending the datepicker to the body, when I click on the datepicker the "popup" disappears... so I've tried moving it into the popup using the [(currently) unaccepted answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733170/930393)...

```
$("#myInput").datepicker({
  ...
  beforeShow: function() {
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").appendTo($("#myPopupDiv"));
  }
});
```

**The problem is** that jQueryUI then sets the `top` and `left` CSS style onthe `#ui-datepicker-div` based on a position relative to the body... but I need it to be relative to the "popup" div.

I've tried setting `position:relative` to `#myPopupDiv`.   And I've also tried setting `top` and `left` as part of the `beforeShow`, but those values are immediately overwritten.

**Is there anyway to make it position correctly?**

Please see the following simple example, where the input is at 50px/100px, but the datepicker now appears at 100px/200px...

```js
$("input").datepicker({
  beforeShow: function() {
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").appendTo($("#myPopup"));
  }
});
```

```css
#myPopup {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPopup">
  <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the singleton can be set with `$.datepicker._pos = [x, y]`.

However, each time the datepicker dialog shows up, it sets the `_pos` to `null` and therefore recalculates the position at the subsequent use.

In your case, the following would set the position each time before opening.

```
$("input").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function() {
        $.datepicker._pos = [20, 0];
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").appendTo($("#myPopupDP"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @miwin - although this isn't perfect, it does allow me to at least figure out the position/height of the input within the "popup" and set it via the `_pos`. (Note, it should be `[0,20]` to go under the input.) I have other things I need to sort now before I come back to this work